# Boto3 Upload Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose

I have a very strange issue with uploading to S3 from Boto. In our (Elastic-Beanstalk-)deployed instances, we have no problems uploading to S3, and other developers with the same S3 credentials also have no issues. However, when locally testing, using the same `Dockerfile`, I can upload files up to exactly 1391 bytes, but anything 1392 bytes and above just gives me a connection that times out and retries a few times.

```
2018-03-27 18:14:34 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxx.s3.amazonaws.com
2018-03-27 18:14:34 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxx.s3.xxx.amazonaws.com
2018-03-27 18:15:14 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO Resetting dropped connection: xxx.s3.xxx.amazonaws.com
```

I've tried this with every variant of uploading to S3 from Boto, including `boto3.resource('s3').meta.client.upload_file`, `boto3.resource('s3').meta.client.upload_fileobj`, and `boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('xxx').put_object`.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Some incompatibility with MTU size?

Comment: @jarmod This might actually be the problem...if I set `network_mode: host` in `docker-compose.yml` for the problematic service, it works. This isn't an actual solution for me, since it introduces other breaking changes, but at least I have a lead now. Thanks!